# How to display values of a property from item in ListBoxes multibinding in a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selecteditem

I have a `TextBox` and I want to show value of a property of the selected item in code behind (with some event, for example, `MouseDown`)

Property is of type `Int16`.

I saw similar questions here, but:

```
TextBox2.Text = ((Helmet) listhelmets.SelectedItems).protection;
```

Doesn't work for me and so don't other advice I saw.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listweapons" Height="214" Width="248" ItemsSource="{Binding ListWeapon}" 
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Canvas.Left="211" Canvas.Top="72" 
         PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="weapons_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
         PreviewMouseMove="weapons_PreviewMouseMove" 
         SelectedValuePath="attack">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Width="56" Height="61"/>
                <TextBox Height="30" Width="30">
                    <Binding Path="_attack" />
                </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast object of type `ListBox.SelectedItemCollection` to type `Helmet`, So you should use `SelectedItem` property of the `listhelmets` instead of `SelectedItems` like this:

```
TextBox2.Text = ((Helmet) listhelmets.SelectedItem).protection;
```

Also don't forget to use `ToString()` in the end of the line if `protection` is not `string`.

Comment: and what if i wanted to calculate two values from two listboxes? and show the result in textbox @user2946329

Comment: @NickShepard...Get values from each `ListBoxes` with this approach, store them in two variable then do your calculation and finally set the result to `TextBox.Text` as `String`.